# C# currency permutations

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, permutation, currency

Just to let everyone know, this is the first time I've ever asked for help on stack overflow. I usually search the site and find a satisfactory answer or dig further on MSDN or other sites. But this time I am seriously stuck.

I received a programming problem from a recruiter that I must complete to submit to the client to see if they want to call me in. Here is the challenge: For any given value determine the number of ways said value can be represented by denominations $100, $50, $20, $10, $5, $1, .25, .10, .05, .01

I have never taken trigonometry or calculus nor have I ever encountered something this mathematically complex in my 14 years of programming. They want the answer in C# as it is a Microsoft .NET shop.

The recruiter gave me another candidate's code which he submitted. This person must be a brilliant mathemetician as she truly wrote the entire algorithim to achieve the desired result. I plugged it into a webpage and it does in fact satisfy the requirements. The problem is that I can't even figure it out and understand it in a way that would allow me to write my own implementation.

I really badly want this job as it is at a startup in NYC that sounds great. I was able to answer the second problem as it was an architecture/design question but this one is confounding me.

BTW I looked up the coin change problem and knapsack type problems on Wikipedia and it is well beyond my mathematical skills. I can't even read the answers as I don't understand calculus. So I need some serious help on this one.

Here is her code which does work BTW:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var numberToSplit = new List<int>() {123};  
    foreach (int a in numberToSplit)
    {
        Response.Write(a + "  can be split in ");
        foreach (List<double> splits in GetDenominations(a).Values)
        {
            foreach (double b in splits)
            {
                Response.Write(b + ",");
            }
            //next split
            Response.Write("<br/>");
        }      
        Response.Write("<br/>");
    }
}

public Dictionary<double, List<double>> GetDenominations(int value)
{
    var denominations = new List<double> {100, 50, 20,10,5,1,0.25,0.10,0.05,0.01};
    var AllPossibleSplits = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>();
    var hightestdenomination = 100.0;

    while (hightestdenomination != 0)
    {
        var remainingDenominations =
                denominations.Where(a => (a <= value && !AllPossibleSplits.Keys.Contains(a)));

        if (remainingDenominations.Count() > 0)
            hightestdenomination = remainingDenominations.Max();
        else
            hightestdenomination = 0;

        var splits = new List<double>(); 

        if (hightestdenomination != 0)
        {
            int valueToSplit = value;
            while (valueToSplit > 0)
            {
                foreach (double denomination in remainingDenominations.Where(a => a <= valueToSplit))
                {
                    int absoluteValue = (int) (valueToSplit/denomination);
                    valueToSplit = valueToSplit - (int) (absoluteValue*denomination);
                    int absoluteValueSplit = 0;

                    while (absoluteValueSplit < absoluteValue)
                    {
                        splits.Add(denomination);
                        absoluteValueSplit++;
                    }
                }
           }   
        }

        AllPossibleSplits[hightestdenomination] = splits;
    }

    return AllPossibleSplits;
}
```

Comment: Aren´t you scared they see this post?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't want to help you to get a job by pretending you're  more capable than you are, and I hope others feel the same way.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps if you have a specific question where you're stuck? What have you tried? By the way on the wikipedia I don't see any calculus or anything, so what are the things you don't understand? What part of the code you don't understand?

Comment: Can only say Try step by step debugging and it should be clear ...

Comment: @John Skeet: Whilst I do agree, I believe that pointing someone into the right direction by, for example, telling him what kind of algo could solve a specific problem, is a different story. After all he will still have to do the research and the implementation, and thats what counts imho, not knowing each and every algo by heart. What also counts is resourcefulness, i.e. knowing where to get answers when being stuck.

Comment: Btw. The solution doesn't find all possible splittings. Ex. 60€ can also split into 20,20,10,10. And the algo can go into an endless loop, if there is no possible splitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at it as a tree traversal problem:

Here you progress trough the tree and check for the following things.

```
Is the cost of the path currently lower then what I want 
 -> Go deeper in the tree

Is the cost of the path currently higher then what I want 
 -> Stop

Is the cost of the path currently the same as what I want 
 -> Permutation found
```

Here is an example: You want to get all possible permutations of $25, with 5, 10 and 20 dollar bills. Blue means that the `cost < 25`, red means `cost > 25` and green means `cost = 25`
[image]
*IMAGE DISCLAIMER: Perhaps some errors in it, but well you get the idea*

Also, if you do it like this, it will give permutations like 5,5,5,10 <> 10,5,5,10 so keep a list of the solutions you already have, so you don't get these multiples. Also this tree has a somewhat large (disputable) branching factor (10), so if you're getting big numbers there are a LOT of possible options. Don't go creating the whole tree first and traversing through it. It can add up (I can't imagine how many possibilities there are to make like $1.000.000).

Answer (score 2):

Well,
The posted algorithm only gives you a glance at all possible permutations, tried it with value 1 it gives answers like:

- 1
- 0,25 , 0,25 , 0,25 , 0,25
- 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1
  .
  .
  .

But thats only a glance at the whole answer there is missing answers like
0,25 , 0,25 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1 , 0,1
to just mention one.
Implementing your own algorithm is a good way to do.
I am a trainee at computational sciences and i can think of a algorithm for that at the top of my head, not as sophisticated, but working.
The guy that posted right before me gave a nice hint:
go from largest to smallest possible split, calculate the maximum amount of occurences and go on with smaller amounts till you end up with 0 rest over.
To get all possible solutions it is a bit more work, but the solution that you provided gives a solution for different maximum amount.

Comment: If this Answer was appropriate, i would appreciate you accept it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at a [Greedy Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Although I feel as it is an interview for a job you should be able to write this code I am more willing to give you a push in the right direction.
This is a classic programming task requiring simple math and I will explain below.
Think about having 1 of each of the denominations, how would you separate them in real life.
Well first you would make a pile of each denomination which in this case corresponds to a variable i.e var hundredDollarNotes, var fiftyDollarNotes, or alternatively an object with properties to that effect.

while your amount is not equal to zero.
take 100 dollars off amount and add one to hundredDollarNotes variable, repeat until cannot take 100 dollars off.
Continue with lower amounts till you have no amount left.

And there you have it a Greedy Algorithm in a nut shell.

Answer (score -1):

Dont make the problem harder then it is.

Lets say you have 51 coins. Use the biggest bill you have (50) 51-50=1
Then use the biggest coin you have (1) 1-1=1

And there you are.

The code simply walks through the entire list of value and uses the biggest bill/denomination possible and does the same for whatever is left till nothing is left.

Comment: Your solution answers a completely different question: Your solution provides the minimum amount of notes/coins to pay $51. However, he is asking for the number of ways in which you can pay $51. i.e: 20+20+10+1, 10+10+10+10+10+1, ...

Comment: Simply repeat the solution given for each possible denominations. And search for all edge cases. I'd brute force it starting with simple set of permutations. (The answer mentioning Greedy Algorithm is wrong too)